Android Studio Debugging - Activity class does not exist
I'm developing an application. To do this, I mainly use Virtual Devices.
At the start of the project I was able to push my application onto a physical smartphone and it worked.
But it's impossible to launch the application:
Activity class {my.package.name/my.package.name.AuthenticationActivity} does not exist
I created a virtual device based on the same version as the physical device. (API 34 / Android 14). The app works on the virtual but not the physical.

Can you share your AndroidManifest.xml file?

solved by separating intent-filter from :
<activity
        android:name=".LauncherActivity"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="${appScheme}" android:host="${appHost}" android:port="${appHostPort}" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

to :
<activity
        android:name=".LauncherActivity"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:scheme="${appScheme}" android:host="${appHost}" android:port="${appHostPort}" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

